# How can I pass commits through multiple git repositories?

Tags: git

[image: chain git]

As seen in the picture, the Laptop has no VPN access (also cannot connect to the Desktop). Therefore to provide code to the git, it needs to be going through another git server.
How do I do that exactly?

I failed because after cloning `B` from `A`, I cannot push it to the *bare* `C` repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a different remote to your local repository :
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

Answer (score 1):

"I cannot push to the bare C repo". You should be able to do that I think. Try the following on desktop

```
git clone [copied_url_A]
# send copy of repo on C
git remote add origin_C [copied_url_C]
git push origin_C --mirror
# here origin points to A, origin_C points to C
```

And on laptop

```
git clone [copied_url_C]
# do changes
git commit -m "message"
git push origin --mirror
# here origin points to C
```

And on desktop again

```
git pull origin_C
git push origin --mirror
# here origin points to A, origin_C points to C
```